# How to connect gdb debug chain for RISCV spike in jetbrains CLion?

Tags: gdb, clion, riscv, openocd

RISCV behavior model SPIKE, support debugging through rbb port. So we can debug it by gdb.

In the following picture, I setup SPIKE rbb_port at :18700, openocd connect to spike and service at :3973， gdb connect to openocd via :3973.

```
                                  :3973             :18700
```

It likes this: riscv64-unkonwn-elf-gdb --------> openocd --------> rbb of SPIKE

[gdb connect to spike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S97I0.png)

You can found we use a specified gdb.

**I think i can debug elf file on SPIKE after mounting these tools (riscv64-unkonwn-elf-gdb) into jetbrains CLion.  **

I tried some configuration in CLion, But not work.

I tried two configuraion

1. Remote debug. This looks like debug remote target via some data path.

[remote debug config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b60Rf.png)

2. **OpecOCD download. This looks like meet my request**, but i can specify my openocd file to do any more.

[OpenOCD config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bnGt.png)
[OpenOCD result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76vQK.png)

[OpenOCD location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNnTJ.png)

I manual specify a formal openocd path, It make sense.
[setting openocd successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1XK5.png)

====================== **BUT** =====================================

Clion need tcl_port do some thing. **Is any one know this isuue?**

[CLion run error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxL28.png)

[CLion debug error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or82m.png)

dobule check, gdb do not need tcl_port from openocd.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Creating an "Embedded GDB Server" run/debug configuration (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/embedded-gdb-server.html#gdbserver-config) and recreate in it everything in the command line.